# I can't find SqlServerDriver on java project

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server and insert the data into the database. I have a class person, main and DataBaseInfo. I have download maven library for all the errors I had and it didn't work. I don't know why.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
        <bean id='data' class='com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'>  
        <property name='driverClassName' value ='java.sql.DriverManager'></property>
        <property name='dataSource' value ='jdbc:sqlserver://10.222.115.11:1433;databaseName=Test;integratedSecurity=true'></property>
        <property name='username' value='HmgDbUser'></property>
        <property name='password' value='123456'></property>
        </bean>
        <bean id='template' class='org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate'>  
        <property name='dataSource' ref ='data'></property>
        </bean>
        <bean id='dbi' class='test1.DataBaseInfo'>  
        <property name='template' ref ='template'></property>
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

My pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
    <name> Spring boots test</name>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssqljdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

My Main

```java
package test1;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {
    //jdbc:sqlserver:10.200.105.11;databaseName=test;integratedSecurity=true
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext conx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");
        DataBaseInfo di = (DataBaseInfo)conx.getBean("dbi");
        int ins=di.insertPerson(new Person("abdulaziz","riyadh","Saudi","Developer"));
        System.out.println(ins);
    }
}
```

When I run it, this error occurs:

```
Oct 28, 2018 4:35:01 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] for bean with name 'data' defined in class path resource [bean.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] for bean with name 'data' defined in class path resource [bean.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1385)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:663)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1491)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:826)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at test1.Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1015)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:413)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:437)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1430)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1374)
    ... 10 more
```

My java version

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to load class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953444/unable-to-load-class-com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserverdriver)

Comment: Please read the exception: _"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0"_ Something is pulling in a newer version of the driver.

Comment: Specifically you are pulling in two different version (one on test, and one on compile scope, and that last one is compiled for Java 10). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Use JDK version 10 while compiling your maven module. Version 10 since the exception you have supplied indicates so. Class file format 54 corresponds to Java 10. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout).
2. Use a version of the JDBC driver compiled for JDK version 8 or matching the JDK version you want to use. But do check the documentation of your database as well, to ensure you pick up the correct driver implementation. Here's one for example:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
       <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
       <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Comment: my java version 
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use low version jdbc driver from maven